# Create a Timer which execute a SQL Query for Example after 20 min?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

in front of a Room i have a Panel. That Panel is displaying the occupancy time, for example 14:00 - 15:30. If someone want to use that Room for that time he has to push a CHECK_IN Button on the Panel. So the system knows there is someone in the Room. Now i want that if nobody use that Button after 20 min from 14:00, the occupancy time should be canceled.

i have already written the Query for the cancel.
But i need something similar to a Timer, which execute the Query after 20 min. 
How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149618.aspx) and put your cancel code in the callback.

```
public void StartCheckin(int dueTime)
{
    var t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(CancelCheckin));
    t.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void CancelCheckin(object state)
{
    // cancel checkin
    // dispose of timer
    ((Timer)state).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: `t` should be declared as field because it will be GC'd long before 20 mins.

Comment: @James it would be nice if you explained on where to put `StartChecking` call, etc.

Comment: @the_joric Not under this circumstance, the timer is kept alive as it is referenced by the callback. Timers are not GC'd whilst they are active.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek that's up to OP where they want to call it, they haven't posted any code so I can't offer an opinion on that.

Comment: But if I was new to the topic I wouldn't also know where to put this code. I belive, your answer is not only intended to help OP but also everybody that comes across similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Timer` object in C#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx